# How to embed a Pygame display in PyQt4 MainWindow?

Tags: python, pygame, pyqt4

I am programming a GUI with PyQt4 and want to embed a Pygame display as a central widget.

I have a **QMainWindow** which uses a pygame element from another class as a central Widget. I already tried to use a pygame surface and it worked so far... but I'm worried about the fact, that pygame surface is made for drawing images to the screen. *For example* `pygame.display.update()` *doesn't work with a common surface*.

```
class GameWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super(GameWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        pygame.init()
        surface = pygame.Surface((width * 1.3, height * 0.4))
        surface.fill((64, 128, 192, 224))
        w=surface.get_width()
        h=surface.get_height()

        pygame.draw.circle(surface, (255, 255, 255, 255), (300, 300), 50)
        self.data=surface.get_buffer().raw
        self.image=QtGui.QImage(self.data,w,h,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp=QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawImage(width / 7, height / 6, self.image)
        qp.end()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(GameWidget(height, width))
        self.setGeometry(200, 50, width, height)
        self.show()
```

I just want to know how to embed a pygame display in my PyQt4 MainWindow. At the moment I have a surface with a circle inside but on the long run I think this won't work.

Comment: Although it is not impossible to integrate pygame with qt, it is very problematic and [not recommended by the pygame devs](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui#The%20user%20perspective).

Comment: Thank you for your help ekhumoro! I am now trying to do it without a PyQt Window.